# How to create a step-by-step tutorial for first-time visitors to a web page (React)?

Tags: reactjs, animation

Apologies if I don't explain this well, but I've seen something like this on certain websites (unfortunately can't think of an example right now).

Sometimes if I visit a website for the first time, the site will guide me through the entire document and highlight certain sections e.g., "Use this button here to add a new item" while the rest of the page is greyed out, and then you click `Next step` which takes you to the next feature, and so on.

It'll be somewhat similar to this (but styled nicer) :[image: example]

Is there a way (or package) to do this with React?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this feature is called **Product Tours**

This library can help you - https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride

Also, I found an article using this library on Smashing Magazine - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/08/guide-product-tours-react-apps/